# How i can get changes in DB postgresql without triggers

Tags: postgresql, change-data-capture

I have database, and in this database ~10 users changes rows, how i can get this changes and user who changed, without triggers. I tried read WAL, and there no info about who what change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WAL only records the information necessary to repeat a data modification, nothing else.

The only ways to get the information you want are either a trigger or parsing the log file (after setting `log_statement = 'mod'` and setting `log_line_prefix` to contain `%u`).

Comment: thanks, it's a little progress, but i still don't know WHO execute query, in the log i see <unnamed>

Comment: You have to set `log_line_prefix` so that the database user is logged.